# Python cant see installed module

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, module, snappy

I downloaded Snappy library sources for working with compression and everything was great on one machine, but it didn't work on another machine. They have completely same configurations of hardware/OS + python 2.7.3.

All I was doing is "./configure && make && make install".

There were 0 errors during any of these processes and it installed successfully to the default lib directory, but python cant see it anyhow. help('modules') and pip freeze doesn't show snappy on the second machine and as the result I cant import it.

I tried even 'to break' structure and install it to different lib catalogs, but even that didn't work. I don't think if its related to system environment variables, since python should have completely same configuration on any of these machines (Amazon EC2).

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found python-snappy on github and installed it via python. Not a permanent solution, but at least something.